# How to show multiple location on map in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, google-maps, asp.net-core-mvc, location

I need work with map in my site but I do not know where to start. I searched the internet, but I can not find a proper answer. I write my questions below and I hope you can help me:

1. What is the best map I can use? Otherwise the Google map if I need?
2. In my website, my user can mark the map and write some description for that location. So I have to many location and I want show them at once when the user open the map on my site. How to do this?
3. Also when the user clicks on a mark, the description of them should be shown to the user.
4. How can I limit the radius of the displayed marks according to the user's current location?

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Leaflet](https://leafletjs.com/) that is an open source JavaScript library used to build web mapping applications and has many features and events that can solve your concerns.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. i going to read it right now.